# 'OR' 2 like statement in a CASE statement- bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My code is as follows, I want to merge 4 like statement as 1 in a case statement.

```
SELECT
  * ,
CASE
    WHEN LOWER(campaign_name) LIKE ('bra_de_%'OR'%-de'OR'vid_de_%'OR 'de_%') THEN 'de'
ELSE '0'
END AS country,
FROM abc
```

can someone support me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using BigQuery [`REGEXP_CONTAINS`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10220936) function, and concatenating your patterns with `|`, like this:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(campaign_name), 
                                 r'^bra[_]de[_].*|.*-de$|^vid[_]de[_].*|^de[_].*')     
            THEN 'de'
            ELSE '0'
       END AS country
FROM abc
```

Comment: It seems the regular expression isn't correct.  Underscore( _ ) in `LIKE`  have special meaning of a single character.

Comment: And you need to use ^ and $ in regular expression.  Without them, result of both will not be the same.